# Where can you buy US craft beer in Europe that will ship to other EU countries?

Tags: distribution, craft-beers

anyone know where you can buy US/American craft beers in Europe. Which shops/websites sell US craft beer and will ship it to other EU countries? Or any wholesalers/distributors to contact.

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't know which EU country you're referring to, here are some of my picks that ship to Sweden.

- shop.mikkeller.dk
- boxbeers.dk
- www.bieresgourmet.be
- www.bier-deluxe.de
- www.biere-revolution.com
- www.beergium.com

Answer (score 2):

**www.beersofeurope.co.uk** are very good, used them 4 times.

**www.beersofeurope.co.uk/usa** lists a number of beers, just a case of scrolling through and selecting into the cart/basket.

Delivery is £7.50 but I find it's worth paying a bit extra to get what you want / try new beers.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend www.alesbymail.co.uk I used them at Christmas 2014 to send a mixed case (chosen by myself) to my family in France. Can't remember exact European delivery costs but it was very reasonable compared to the cost of the beers or I wouldn't have used it. Check their Twitter @alesbymail for regular discount codes. (I have no affiliation with them other than being a satisfied customer).